# Adding a field to a view based on another row in the group

Tags: sql, view

I'm looking at data for ticket sales. I need to see all the **tickets in a transactions** where a discount was applied to **at least one ticket**. Only one discount per transaction is allowed, though multiple tickets may have that discount. (For example, a AAA discount can be applied to up to 4 adult tickets, though more tickets may be purchased. I need data on all tickets purchased when the AAA Discount was used.)

End users will access the data in a view through Excel, then pivot and slice based on discount type and date. In creating the view, how can I apply the discount code from one ticket row to all tickets in the transaction?

```
SELECT 
    JnlTickets.TransNo,
    JnlHeaders.FiscalDate,
    JnlTickets.DiscNo AS DiscountNumber,
    LEFT(JnlHeaders.agency,1) AS Agency,
    Discounts.Name

FROM dbo.JnlHeaders (nolock) 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.JnlTickets (nolock) 
        ON dbo.JnlHeaders.TranNo=dbo.JnlTickets.TransNo
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Discounts (nolock) 
        ON dbo.JnlTickets.DiscNo=dbo.DISCOUNTS.DiscountID

GROUP BY JnlTickets.TransNo, 
        JnlTickets.DiscNo, 
        JnlHeaders.FiscalDate, 
        LEFT(JnlHeaders.agency,1), 
        Jnltickets.coupons,
        Discounts.Name
HAVING(JnlHeaders.FiscalDate BETWEEN '2012-03-07' AND '2012-03-08')
     AND 
    (Jnltickets.transno IN (SELECT  JnlTickets.TransNo 
                            FROM JnlTickets 
                            WHERE JnlTickets.DiscNo > '1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do it is to derive a table from tickets and discounts and retrieving distinct transaction number and discount id and name, and then join it back to tickets on transaction number. This will work only if you really have only one discount type per transaction.

Note: last part of having filters out all transactions where no discount was applied. This can now be achieved by changing left join of derived table to inner join.

```
SELECT 
    JnlTickets.TransNo,
    JnlHeaders.FiscalDate,
    TransactionsWithDiscounts.DiscNo AS DiscountNumber,
    LEFT(JnlHeaders.agency,1) AS Agency,
    TransactionsWithDiscounts.Name

FROM dbo.JnlHeaders (nolock) 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.JnlTickets (nolock) 
        ON dbo.JnlHeaders.TranNo=dbo.JnlTickets.TransNo
    left join
    (
       select distinct JnlTickets.TransNo, JnlTickets.DiscNo, Discounts.Name
         from dbo.JnlTickets (nolock) 
             LEFT JOIN dbo.Discounts (nolock) 
               ON dbo.JnlTickets.DiscNo = dbo.DISCOUNTS.DiscountID
        where JnlTickets.DiscNo > '1' -- or is not null? 
    ) TransactionsWithDiscounts
      ON JnlTickets.TransNo = TransactionsWithDiscounts.TransNo
GROUP BY JnlTickets.TransNo, 
        TransactionsWithDiscounts.DiscNo, 
        JnlHeaders.FiscalDate, 
        LEFT(JnlHeaders.agency,1), 
        Jnltickets.coupons,
        TransactionsWithDiscounts.Name
HAVING(JnlHeaders.FiscalDate BETWEEN '2012-03-07' AND '2012-03-08')
     AND 
    (Jnltickets.transno IN (SELECT  JnlTickets.TransNo 
                            FROM JnlTickets 
                            WHERE JnlTickets.DiscNo > '1'));
```